# How to Make This Test case to Fail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a test case as shown below . it compares 2 data and returns PASS if both data is identical .

the issue is i want this **test to fail if there is data mismatch**

CODE is

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.id(WebelementID));

String Content = TxtBoxContent.getAttribute("value");

String ExcelData = Generic.getXlCellValue(xlpath, sheetName, rownum, cellnum);

Content.equals(ExcelData);

Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- PASS",true);
```

Comment: Test get does not return anything, it just compares to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make your test fail, you can put a habit of writing Assertions whenever you have something boolean to check

```
Assert.assertTrue(Content.equals(ExcelData));
```

In case your Test should pass for a False condition, then your Assert would become

```
Assert.assertFalse(Content.equals(ExcelData));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are on TestNg then to fail test case use below thow

```
Assert.fail();
```

or

```
Assert.fail("Write your custom error message");
```

Reporter.log() is for logging, it will not fail your test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
if(Content.equals(ExcelData))
{ 
Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- PASS",true);
}
else
{
 Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- Fail",true);
}
```

Comment: i am using testNG framework . and above code is just to verify if the data in the text box is same as what it is in excel sheet . my question is if it is same it will show data verification pass . if its's not same i want the test case to stop there itself and show the test is failed so that i can see where it is failing ... if i use the above code .the testNG report it is showing the test case is passed

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Content.equals(ExcelData)){
        Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- PASS",true);
    }else{
        System.out.println(LocationName+ " Data Verification Failed");
    }
```

In the above code when the condition is not met then it will show in console that the test case has failed along with the location name.