# Assert text in PDF using PDFBox - Selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I use the below method where I need to find whether a text is present in the PDF file that I have downloaded.

```
public void iShouldVerify() throws Throwable {
        export_inspections.verifyPDFContent("zzz");



public boolean verifyPDFContent(String reqTextInPDF) {

boolean flag = false;

PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
String parsedText = null;

try {
    File file = new File("/Users/mohand/Downloads/1956_ANewChecklistTemplate1Updated_BigTurnip_270618.pdf");
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));

    parser.parse();
    cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
    pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);

    pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
    parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
} catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
    System.err.println("URL string could not be parsed " + e2.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
    try {
        if (cosDoc != null)
            cosDoc.close();
        if (pdDoc != null)
            pdDoc.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++");
System.out.println(parsedText);
System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++");
System.out.println(reqTextInPDF);


if (parsedText.contains(reqTextInPDF)) {
    flag = true;
}

return flag;
}
```

The problem is the code passes even if there is no text called as "zzz" in the PDF, the code runs.

How do I assert this? Or is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of `export_inspections.verifyPDFContent("zzz");`. Why?

Comment: I don't really do anything with the return value as this is a part of my testing framework.

Comment: But how would the framework know that something went wrong? `verifyPDFContent("zzz")` is your own method. Or is your question how to "fail" Selenium if something returns false?

Comment: I was under the assumption that `if (parsedText.contains(reqTextInPDF)) {
    flag = true;
}` will take care of it

Comment: `flag` is just your local private variable IMHO. I suspect this is rather a Selenium question than a PDFBox question. If you don't get an answer soon, please create a new question without PDFBox that asks how to fail Selenium if a condition is false. Your PDFBox code is OK, although a bit too complex (see answer by draxil).

Comment: Will do that. Will give it few hours. Thanks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089243/how-to-make-this-test-case-to-fail

Comment: I used `Assert.assertTrue(parsedText.equals(reqTextInPDF));` for assertion and it's failing even if the text is present in the PDF. Because I am able to see the string that I need for assertions in `parsedText` and in `reqTextInPDF`. Is there any other thing I need to pay attention in PDF box?

Comment: But you used "contains" before??? Note that he extracted text may contain invisible chars and newlines and CRs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified version:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;



public class X {
    public static boolean verifyPDFContent(String reqTextInPDF) throws IOException{

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
        doc.close();
        System.out.println(text);
        return text.contains(reqTextInPDF);
    }

    public static void main( String [] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println(verifyPDFContent("Charity"));
    }
}
```

This works for me, I wan't 100% able to tell which PDFbox you are using, so if this doesn't compile we may be on different versions (I'm on 2.0.3).

Comment: Don't forget to close your document, use try-with-resources. The current PDFBox version is 2.0.10, and soon 2.0.11.

Comment: I tried this way, but even though the PDF doesn't have the text, the code runs fine. How do you verify here that it checks the PDF extracted text with the string that we search for?

Comment: The .contains would return false if the text were not present, bear in mind I've used a different string to match one in my test PDF. When you say "the code runs fine", what do you expect? All I'm doing here is printing out the true or false. If you'd like it to (say) throw an exception then that would be simple enough?