# How to explicitly or manually fail a test case in JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit, rest-assured

In my Java / RestAssured / TestNG framework, I want to write an assertion with the following structure

```
if(responseString.equals("Good Response!")) {
  // perform additional assertions here
} else if(responseString.equals("Bad Response!")) {
  // just fail the test case right here and now
}
```

What is the best way to go about simply failing the test case without asserting anything else?

Comment: This could be considered a duplicate of the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089243/how-to-make-this-test-case-to-fail but the other question is poorly worded and it is not clear whether it is actually referring to JUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the if, instead just do:

```
assertEquals("Good Response!", responseString);
// perform additional assertions here
```

If you simply want to fail:

```
fail("I failed because...");
```

Comment: Obviously that is a good solution for a simple assertion on a string, but I also want to be able to trigger an assertion explicitly from within a conditional.  A simple assertEquals may not always fit the bill if the assertion only applies to certain application states.

Comment: Thanks, fail("message"); is what I was looking for here

Answer (score 1):

`Assert.assertEquals(true, false);`